# SQL - Count by range

Tags: sql, mysql, database

How can I select the number of population by age group

```
count ( 0->10)
count ( 11->20)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In SQL, how can you "group by" in ranges?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232387/in-sql-how-can-you-group-by-in-ranges)

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247630/mysql-group-by-age-range-including-null-ranges might also be a solution to count the group-by age-range

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are other question about the same, you can found the solution on: [In SQL, how can you "group by" in ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232387/in-sql-how-can-you-group-by-in-ranges)

The syntax is valid for mysql too.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT FLOOR(age / 10), COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY FLOOR(age / 10)
```

Manipulate the `age / 10` expression to get the exact ranges. This will return `0` for ages 0-9, `1` for ages 10-19, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but if have a range as : 0-7, 8-15, 16-30,