# Group by age from date field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a DoB field. I want to categories/group all users based on their age into these groups:

1. **<20**
2. **20-25**
3. **25-30**
4. **30-35**
5. **35-40**
6. **40-50**
7. **>50**

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specifically are you having problems with? Can you show some sample data and explain the schema that corresponds?

Comment: dont know where to start

Comment: Once you've grouped the users, what do you want to do? e.g. select a count of how many fall in each group?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247630/mysql-group-by-age-range-including-null-ranges

Comment: @cularis thanks. Post this as this answer i will rate it as a the answer

Comment: Well, if the author says it's a duplicate, it should probably be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN age < 20 THEN 'Under 20'
        WHEN age BETWEEN 20 and 29 THEN '20 - 29'
        WHEN age BETWEEN 30 and 39 THEN '30 - 39'
        WHEN age BETWEEN 40 and 49 THEN '40 - 49'
        WHEN age BETWEEN 50 and 59 THEN '50 - 59'
        WHEN age BETWEEN 60 and 69 THEN '60 - 69'
        WHEN age BETWEEN 70 and 79 THEN '70 - 79'
        WHEN age >= 80 THEN 'Over 80'
        WHEN age IS NULL THEN 'Not Filled In (NULL)'
    END as age_range,
    COUNT(*) AS count    
    FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) AS age FROM gamers) as derived    
    GROUP BY age_range    
    ORDER BY age_range
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  If you don't have a lot of records, you could do something like

```
select floor((datediff(now(),DOB_at)/365)/5) as year_group, count(*) 
   from users 
   group by floor((datediff(now(),DOB)/365)/5)
```

This has to be tweaked to group the DOB that are under 20 or over 50.

A slightly better way would be to have a lookup table with your groups, that would have two columns, year_diff and group_name.

```
 year_diff group_name
 ....values.....
 18        '<20'
 19        '<20'
 20        '20-25'
 21        '20-25'
 22        '20-25'
 23        '20-25'
 24        '20-25'
 25        '20-25'
 26        '26-30'
 ....values.....
```

Your query would then be

```
select dob_lookup.group_name, count(*) 
   from users 
      join dob_lookup on floor((datediff(now(),users.DOB)/365)/5) = dob_lookup.year_diff
   group by dob_lookup.group_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is to append one more field to table (like 'age_group') and fill it on inserting. Then you can easily group it by using `group by age_group`.