# SQL Group by Age Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by

SQL 2005, 
I have a table with a column 'ages_c', I need to group the records by age ranges. 
This is the query that I found on this site and it's getting me 90% there but the 'group by' is erroring, *Invalid column name 'age_range'*

```
 select 
  case
   when age_c <18 then 'Under 18'
   when age_c between 18 and 24 then '18-24'
   when age_c between 25 and 34then '25-34'
 END as age_range, 
 Count(*) as count
 from contacts
 group by age_range
 order by age_range
```

When I group and order by 'age_c' my result is:

```
  Under 18  1
  18-24 1
  18-24 1
  25-34 1
```

What I want is:

```
 Under 18   1
  18-24 2      
  25-34 1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try it this way instead:

```
 SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN age_c < 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Under 18],
        SUM(CASE WHEN age_c BETWEEN 18 AND 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [18-24],
        SUM(CASE WHEN age_c BETWEEN 25 AND 34 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [25-34]
 FROM contacts
```

Comment: Thanks Joe... I appreciate the simplicity.

Comment: Simple and best!

Answer (score 11):

Group by `age_c` -- age_range isn't a physical column. More specifically, do this:

```
group by case
   when age_c <18 then 'Under 18'
   when age_c between 18 and 24 then '18-24'
   when age_c between 25 and 34then '25-34'
 END
```

Since `age_range` is an aliased column, the `group by` is not aware of it at all. Grouping happens before the column set is calculated. The only clause that you can use your aliases in is `order by`, since that's the only clause that's executed *after* the column set is calculated.

Comment: @Sheridanbulger this is exactly what was asked for and works fine. See an working example at [Grouping By Case Example](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2346/grouping-by-case-example)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. At first glance I saw grouping by just age_c. Did you edit it? In either case, yes that code (or any of the other answers) would work great.

Comment: Thank you. I really didn't think I could use age_range as a colunn because it is an alias. I was following the example on this page: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247630/mysql-group-by-age-range-including-null-ranges

Answer (score 3):

You can't group by a column you create in the query. You'll have to do it like this:

```
SELECT count(*), * FROM 
(
select 
  case
   when age_c <18 then 'Under 18'
   when age_c between 18 and 24 then '18-24'
   when age_c between 25 and 34then '25-34'
 END as age_range 
 from contacts
) t
group by age_range
order by age_range
```

or GROUP BY

```
case
       when age_c <18 then 'Under 18'
       when age_c between 18 and 24 then '18-24'
       when age_c between 25 and 34then '25-34'
END
```

Comment: I'd prefer a temp table to a nested query just because it makes a cleaner looking query, but it's really two sides to the same coin.

Comment: Thanks Mithrandir. This is very close, I had to rearrange it a little to get it to work... but work it does.

Answer (score 1):

If your database supports **FILTER WHERE** syntax then this can be archived in a very elegant way:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(id) FILTER (WHERE (age < 18)) AS "Under 18",
       COUNT(id) FILTER (WHERE (age >= 18 AND age <= 24)) AS "18-24",
       COUNT(id) FILTER (WHERE (age >= 25 AND age <= 34)) AS "25-34"
FROM contacts
```

Or this one if not:

```sql
SELECT count(CASE WHEN (age < 18) THEN id ELSE null END)                AS "Under_18",
       count(CASE WHEN (age >= 18 AND age <= 24) THEN id ELSE null END) AS "18-24",
       count(CASE WHEN (age >= 25 AND age <= 34) THEN id ELSE null END) AS "25-34"
FROM contacts
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that your actual code you're using? It doesn't look like it because you're missing a space between 34 and then. That code would error in SQL. Mind sharing the actual unmodified query?

Anyways, you can use a temp table or a nested query.

```
SELECT
 CASE
  WHEN age_c <18 THEN 'Under 18'
  WHEN age_c BETWEEN 18 AND 24 THEN '18-24'
  WHEN age_c BETWEEN 25 AND 34 THEN '25-34'
END AS age_range, 
INTO #TempAges
FROM contacts
ORDER BY age_c

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TempAges GROUP BY age_range
```

Don't forget to drop the temporary table when you're done with it

Comment: `It doesn't look like it because you're missing a space between 34 and then. That code would error in SQL. ` not really. SQL Server can parse and execute it with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN '20-29'

        WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30-39'

        WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40-49'

           WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN '50-59'


        ELSE '60 AND Older'

    END AS age_group_Frequency,

count (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN '20-29'

        WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30-39'

        WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40-49'

           WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN '50-59'


        ELSE '60 AND Older'

    END) AS age_group
       
     


  FROM

put your statement****

where

*****

  group by 
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN '20-29'

        WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30-39'

        WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40-49'

           WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN '50-59'


        ELSE '60 AND Older'

    END
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't perform Group By operation directly by alias column.
So I tried here by using CTE. It worked well.

```sql
with k
 as
 (
     select  
            case 
             when age >=18 and age < 30 then '18-29'
             when age>=30 and age < 50 then '30-49'
             when age>=50 and age < 60 then '50-60'
            else '60+'
        end as AgeGroup,
        purchase_amount_usd
     from shopping_trends
 )
 select AgeGroup, sum(purchase_amount_usd) as [Purchases by age group], 
 cast(((sum(purchase_amount_usd)*1.0/(select(sum(purchase_amount_usd)) from k))*100)as decimal(10,2))
 as [Purchase% by Age Group]
 from k
 group by AgeGroup
 order by [Purchases by age group] desc
```

[Image shows the code and its output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qivM4.png)

Comment: I used CTE method to do Group By  by AgeGroup Column in my code. It worked well. I uploaded image of code and its output.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include that explanation.