# Efficiently calculating number of results by range in grouped SQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a fairly large database in which every row has a specific class. Every class in turn belongs to a generalized class, which is specified in a separate table. So, in order to find the generalized class of an item, a JOIN has to be performed.

Also, one of the columns contains a certain numeric value, say 'w'. I'm trying to find an efficient query that gives the number of items within a specific range of 'w', grouped by the generalized class. So, for example, one of the result rows would give the breakdown of the number of items in that class with w < 500, 500 < w < 1500 and w > 1500.

Right now, I use a pre-existing view that already joins the generalized class into the result set, so that there's no need for a JOIN in the final query. That final query uses a trick I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247630/mysql-group-by-age-range-including-null-ranges) to calculate the amount of items within a specific range.

```
SELECT generalized_class, 
    SUM(IF(w BETWEEN 1 AND 500, 1, 0)) AS low, 
    SUM(IF(w BETWEEN 500 AND 1500, 1, 0)) AS middle,
    SUM(IF(w > 1500, 1, 0)) AS high
FROM table_vw
GROUP BY generalized_class
```

However, I'm not quite sure whether this is the most efficient way to do it. As the database is fairly large, the entire thing takes over five minutes to complete. I imagine that calculating this sort of stuff is an expensive operation in general, but I'm just wondering whether I could use a different approach that would remove some load. Anyone?

-edit-
The definition of the view is nothing spectacular, it's something like

```
CREATE VIEW table_vw AS SELECT d.id, d.class, c.generalized_class, <more fields>, 
(w_high/w_low)/2 AS w
FROM base_table d
LEFT OUTER JOIN secondary_table c   
    ON (d.class = c.class)
```

I'm pretty sure there's one more left outer join being made to another table, but no rows from that table are used (as I said, it's a pre-existing view, so there's a lot of stuff in it that isn't tailored for this query). The join row 'class' is indexed only in the secondary table.

Comment: What is the view query you're currently using? What are the structure and indexes of the tables you're joining and what does the current explain plan say?

Comment: Please post the definitions of the viwe and its underlying tables.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your query takes so long to execute may be that it doesn't properly use indexes (or doesn't use them at all!).
Use EXPLAIN to see how MySQL executes your query.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html

Another reason may be that MySQL first computes the entire result of the view, then uses that to compute the result of the whole query.
In that case, a solution would be to merge the view definition with your query.

Comment: I've managed to gain some speedup by stripping a few unnecessary fields from the view, but it still takes considerable time. As far as I can see from the EXPLAIN output, indexing will hardly solve the problem. Is there another way to restructure or optimize?