# Avoid repeating results from php+mySQL query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an item table from where I'm fetching the values under 10000 of the *price* column

This is my query in the simplest way:

```
$sql_range_price = "SELECT c.price FROM items WHERE c.price < 10000 AND c.item LIKE '$anyitem' ORDER BY c.price ASC";

$rs_range_price = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql_range_price);
```

Let's say the column fetched has these values:

```
4495
1995
1500
1399
995
890
798
```

And this is how I'm playing with them in PHP:

```
while($row_range_price = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_range_price, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $rprices = $row_range_price["price"];
  switch (true) {
      case $rprices > 9000 && $rprices <= 10000:
          echo "Items between $9000 and $10000";
          break;
      case ($rprices > 8000 && $rprices <= 9000):
          echo "Items between $8000 and $9000";
          break;
      case ($rprices > 7000 && $rprices <= 8000):
          echo "Items between $7000 and $9000";
          break;
      case ($rprices > 6000 && $rprices <= 7000):
          echo "Items between $6000 and $7000";
          break;
      case ($rprices > 5000 && $rprices <= 6000):
          echo "Items between $5000 and $6000";
          break;
      case ($rprices > 4000 && $rprices <= 5000):
          echo "Items between $4000 and $5000";
          break;
      case ($rprices > 3000 && $rprices <= 4000):
          echo "Items between $3000 and $4000";
          break;
      case ($rprices > 2000 && $rprices <= 3000):
          echo "Items between $2000 and $3000";
          break;
      case ($rprices > 1000 && $rprices <= 2000):
          echo "Items between $1000 and $2000";
          break;
      case ($rprices > 0 && $rprices <= 1000):
          echo "Items between $0 and $1000";
          break;
      default:
      {
        echo "No items in price range.";
        break;
      }
    }
```

This would print:

*Items between $0 and $1000

Items between $0 and $1000

Items between $0 and $1000

Items between $1000 and $2000

Items between $1000 and $2000

Items between $1000 and $2000

Items between $4000 and $5000*

What I would like it prints is:

*Items between $0 and $1000

Items between $1000 and $2000

Items between $4000 and $5000*

My questions now are:

1) How to avoid repeating Items *between $0 and $1000* for example. Should I work on the SQL Query or the PHP part?

2) With *if* conditional it takes virtually the same amount of code. Is that ok doing it using *switch*? or is there a better or more efficient way?

Thanks a lot for any help or advice.

*P.S. I'm not a php or mySQL guru. Just saying this because last time I asked something, I I got negative answers from people assuming I should know everything about the subject before asking.*

**UPDATE SOLUTION:**
This is the new QUERY which works now thanks to your help:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN c.price > 0 AND c.price <= 1000 THEN '1000'
    WHEN c.price > 1000 AND c.price <= 2000 THEN '2000'
    WHEN c.price > 2000 AND c.price <= 3000 THEN '3000'
    WHEN c.price > 3000 AND c.price <= 4000 THEN '4000'
    WHEN c.price > 4000 AND c.price <= 5000 THEN '5000'
    WHEN c.price > 5000 AND c.price <= 6000 THEN '6000'
    WHEN c.price > 6000 AND c.price <= 7000 THEN '7000'
    WHEN c.price > 7000 AND c.price <= 8000 THEN '8000'
    WHEN c.price > 8000 AND c.price <= 9000 THEN '9000'
    WHEN c.price > 9000 AND c.price <= 10000 THEN '10000'
 END AS rprice
FROM mytable
WHERE c.price <= 10000 AND c.item LIKE '$item' GROUP BY rprice ASC";
```

I didn't change anything else.

Comment: This looks like a similar situation (different application), and may be of help. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247630/mysql-group-by-age-range-including-null-ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247630/mysql-group-by-age-range-including-null-ranges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your price bands are irregular you could use a case statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
 CASE 
 WHEN price <= 1000 THEN 1000 
 WHEN PRICE <= 5000 THEN 5000
 ELSE 999999
 END
 AS price_band
 ...
```

If your price bands are all exactly the same you could use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
 TRUNCATE(1000 - 1, -3) + 1 AS price_from, 
 TRUNCATE(1000 - 1, -3) + 1000 AS price_to ...
```

As an alternative to using SELECT DISTINCT to elimiate duplicate rows you could use COUNT(*) and GROUP BY to get the number of items in each band.

you could do a similar thing in PHP but using the SQL statment to give you the bands reduces the number of records that have to be passed to PHP.

Comment: SOLVED. Using DISTINCT after SELECT didn't work. I tried to find out why, but no idea. It worked with GROUP BY at the end of the select. Thanks Steve.

Answer (score 1):

Try using SELECT DISTINCT price un your query