# Group ages by city

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, group-by

I'm having hard times with grouping; I'm working on ISTAT (Italian Institute of Statistics) data about my region's population; they give me data for each city and each age (0, 1, 2 and so on) and I need to group ages in class of 10 years (0-9, 10-19, and so on) for EACH city. Example of the first few rows:

```
| ID | CodiceComune | Eta | Celibi | Coniugati | Divorziati | Vedovi | TotMaschi | Nubili | Coniugate | Divorziate | Vedove | TotFemmine |
+----+--------------+-----+--------+-----------+------------+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+--------+------------+
|  1 |        42001 |   0 |     30 |         0 |          0 |      0 |        30 |     22 |         0 |          0 |      0 |         22 |
|  2 |        42001 |   1 |     22 |         0 |          0 |      0 |        22 |     22 |         0 |          0 |      0 |         22 |
|  3 |        42001 |   2 |     27 |         0 |          0 |      0 |        27 |     21 |         0 |          0 |      0 |         21 |
|  4 |        42001 |   3 |     23 |         0 |          0 |      0 |        23 |     26 |         0 |          0 |      0 |         26 |
|  5 |        42001 |   4 |     33 |         0 |          0 |      0 |        33 |     24 |         0 |          0 |      0 |         24
```

where `CodiceComune` is the ISTAT code assigned to each city, `Eta` is age (ranging from 0 to 100), `TotMaschi` is the total number of males having that very age in that city, `TotFemmine` is the total number of females having that very age in that city; you don't need the translation of the other columns since I don't need those data.

What I'd like to get is a view containing, FOR EACH CITY, the total number of males and the total number of females IN EACH AGE CLASS, that is, the number of males in city `42001` being between `0` and `9` years old, and so on.

For the record, I've tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247630/mysql-group-by-age-range-including-null-ranges) but it doesn't fit my purpose and I'm not able to adapt the code in the link to my case; of course I know I can do it in Excel but it will take my whole life since the table has more than 24,000 rows.

Comment: You have already how old are the peoples (Eta) ...

Comment: Yes, I know how many people aged 10 or 34 or whatever in each city but what I need to get is a view where, for each city, tells me how many males and how many females there are in each age class

Comment: I have post an answew you could group by this age by div (integer divisione) by 10. Summing and grouping by Comune...

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT CodiceComune
     , CONCAT(FLOOR((Eta+0.5)/10)*10,'-',(CEILING((Eta+0.5)/10)*10)-1) Age_group
     , SUM(TotMaschi) m
     , SUM(TotFemmine) f 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY CodiceComune
     , FLOOR(Eta/10);
```

Comment: @Ale i tweaked it slightly

Comment: I figured out what FLOOR and CEILING do in the code, but I guess that the magic is in the group by clause, isn't it?

Comment: Well, we could have grouped by `age_group` instead

Answer (score 0):

This will count the number of males for the 10 year range in MySQL

```
SELECT COUNT(TotMaschi) FROM tablename WHERE CodiceComune = 42001 AND eta IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Comment: Come on; that's not very scalable!

Comment: ok, how to it for each city (there are 239 cities in my region) and for each age class and put everything in a single view?

Comment: Thats a start @Strawberry. I cant write the entire code. This may not be the entire answer.

Comment: @ale you need to write a procedure to achieve for all the 239 cities or use help from PHP to attain the end results

Comment: I have no experience at all with PHP; anyway, I slightly modified your code and I got the sum of people in ONE age class for each city; I did

SELECT CodiceComune, SUM(TotMaschi) AS 'Maschi0-9' FROM pop_eta_comuni WHERE Eta BETWEEN 0 AND 9 GROUP BY CodiceComune;

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample for TotMaschi and totFemmine ... the sum of the peoples in the age_range for ten years for each CodiceComune.

```
select CodiceComune, sum(totMaschi), sum(toyFemmine), eta div 10 as age_range 
from tablename 
group by CodiceComune, age_range;
```

Comment: @Strawberry for div this sample is from MYSQL doc` mysql> SELECT 5 DIV 2;
        -> 2`     https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html